# Are NSOperations executed on run-loops? Are there run-loops in every thread? What about OpenGL?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

Recently I realized I don't fully understand what gets run on a run-loop and what does not. So here's a bunch of questions:

1. Is a run-loop something that is only run on the main thread?
2. Does the OpenGL main loop that underlies the entire GUI run on the thread 0 run-loop? (By analogy, in GLUT this would be what calls drawScene()...)
3. Does every thread have a run-loop?
4. Where do NSOperations run?
5. It seems to me that GCD is entirely separate from the run-loops because it is a C library (libdispatch). How does GCD relate to the main GUI run loop?
6. If I use an NSOperationQueue to run multiple NSOperations at once, does each have a run-loop or do I have to write that code (and why would I)?

Thanks

Comment: Re: #1 and #3, there's a [reference for that](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html).

Comment: sort of related to #2: it sounds like you are trying to do openGL stuff, you shouldnt need to mess too much with run loops on your own, you can just use a [CADisplayLink](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/index.html) and just give it the main run loop (or i guess some other one, i havent tried that before myself), and all should work fine

Answer (score 2):

Questions 1 and 3 are the same. Every thread has a run loop, but not every thread *runs* its run loop.

A run loop is an object. Like objects generally, it has state and it has methods which cause it do something, based on that state. It doesn't magically do stuff except when it is invoked. Its state consists of input sources (like network connections or the steam of UI events it gets from the window server) and timers, organized into modes. When the run loop is asked to run, it sleeps in such a way that the OS will wake it up at a particular time or when any of its input sources is ready. It then goes through all of the input sources and timers that are ready to fire and calls the handler function for each. Depending on how it was asked to run, it may loop back and sleep again or it may return. That's all.

Some parts of Cocoa run a run loop on your behalf. Most notably, the application object runs one to wait for events. But on threads other than the main thread, the run loop is not typically running.

There's no "OpenGL main loop" unless you write one, in which case it works however you write it to. GLUT does have a main loop and it's built on the main run loop (which is the run loop of the main thread, which is the original thread of the process). You can see the [implementation](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/samplecode/glut/Listings/GLUTApplication_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000528-GLUTApplication_m-DontLinkElementID_5) in the legacy GLUT code in Apple's documentation. Look for the `-run` method.

`NSOperation`s don't run on their own. Something has to invoke `-start` on an operation object to run that operation. Like everything else in a program, that happens on some thread. Which thread is up to the caller. What the operation does from there is up to the operation object itself. It may be synchronous and do all of its work right there before returning from `-start`, in which case it runs on the thread where it was called. Or, it might be asynchronous and start work on some other thread and then return from `-start` before that work is completed.

It is common to submit operations to operation queues (instance of `NSOperationQueue`). The main operation queue (returned from `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]`) starts all of its operations on the main thread and thus depends on the code in that thread giving time to its run loop. That's usually done by returning out of whatever methods the framework has called, but it can also happen when some APIs run the run loop or event loop within them (for example, `-[NSTask waitUntilExit]` or `-[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:`]).

Other operation queues run operations on worker threads that it controls. This may or may not involve run loops. That would be an implementation detail.

Run loops are not tied to Objective-C. There's a C API for them, [`CFRunLoop`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFRunLoopRef/). The main dispatch queue (obtained using `dispatch_get_main_queue()`) is associated with the main run loop in a program which runs it, like any normal Cocoa app. However, it can instead be associated with whatever thread calls `dispatch_main()` for a program which doesn't run a run loop on the main thread. Whether non-main dispatch queues are related to run loops is, again, an implementation detail (but they aren't ;).

`NSOperation`s don't have run loops, because run loops are associated with threads. When an `NSOperation` is running, it runs on some thread. All threads have run loops associated with them, but, as I said, not all threads run their run loops. You do not "need" to write code related to run loops for an `NSOperation`. Generally, you shouldn't. Sometimes people have their operations run the run loop of the thread they're on in order to allow some run-loop-based API to be notified when some source is ready or event has occurred. There's usually another way to do what they're trying to do that is more efficient with resources.

Comment: On the off-chance he's referring in (2) to Core Animation and its compositor: no, it doesn't run on the main runloop. But calls to `-[UIView drawRect:]` do. Though some kinds of layer can be used to draw in the background — e.g. `CATiledLayer` — subject to the view being written sufficiently carefully.

Comment: That's another implementation detail, but, no, each animation does not have its own thread.

Comment: The other piece that's kind of missing here is that, in the common case, each OS has a 'helper process' that actually manages the animations at the 'GPU texture' level. iOS has Springboard, and OS X has the WindowServer. Your process sets everything up, and then sends a mach message to the helper process, which then takes over the management of the animation/display at the GPU level. If you write the OpenGL code yourself, you're "in-sourcing" that work into your process.